# How to change field's answer when I use gem 'rails_admin'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sum, field, rails-admin

In my project I am using RailsAdmin and have two models, Product & Product_rate.

```
has_many :product_rates
belongs_to :product
```

The code in rails_admin.rb is

```
config.model Product do
  ....
  list do
    field :product_rates
  end
```

I want show the product_rates' rank in the "field :product_rates". The product_rate model looks like this.

```
class ProductRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :rank, :product_id
end
```

The best results can be displayed the rank sum.
For example: Product XX has ranks what are 0,1,0,2. I want to show rank sum in the product_rates, which would be 3.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you add a `total_rank` method to your `Product` model and use that.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_rates

  def total_rank
    product_rates.map(&:rank).inject(:+)
  end
end
```

Then in your `initializers/rails_admin.rb`:

```
config.model Product do
  ....
  list do
    field :total_rank do
      label "Rating"
    end
  end
```

Maybe that doesn't exactly answer your question. [According to the docs](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL) maybe you want to try something like this..

```
 list do
   field :product_rating do
     formatted_value do # used in form views
       value.map(&:rank).inject(:+)  # I'm assuming the value is an array of products
     end
   end
 end
```